# Exclude path from Recommendations Box

Tags: facebook, facebook-recommendations

Is there any way to exclude certain directories and/or files on my site from being included in the Facebook Recommendation Box? I don't want to prevent those pages from being Liked or Recommended; I just don't want them showing up in the Recommendation Box elsewhere on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/, cross domain aggregations don't work currently. 
So, you might consider including those directories and files that you wish to include under a different sub-domain, and only call that path. 
For eg - all pages that need to be included in the Recommendation box - include.YOUR-SITE.com
and pages you wish to exclude be hosted directly under - YOUR-SITE.com.
And when you invoke the fb:recommendations tag, specify the site as -
site="include.YOUR-SITE.com"